# Handling Large Datasets with With X axis Charts

Tags: javascript, flotr

I am using FLOTR API to display charts

I have some large sets of data for Six Months . For example

```
var jsonData = [August 19, 2004',August 20, 2004',August 21, 2004',August 22, 2004',.........,January 1 , 2005] ;
```

Like this for 6 Months .

But inside X axis I need to display only the Months date values .

```
Flotr.draw(
xaxis:{
tickFormatter: function(n)
{
return ;
},
}
```

Please tell me , what will be the best solution for this ??

Comment: Could anybody please tell me as how to do this thing ?? I need it very badly sir .

Comment: @James, true... I didn't see that when I answered, oh well.  @user663724, it's good form to mark answers as "accepted" if they help you, see the FAQ under "How do I ask questions here?"

Answer (score 0):

In your xaxis object, you need to use the `ticks` property to specify the ticks you want.

It would look something like this:

```
xaxis: {
  ...
  ticks: [[<timestamp>,'August, 2004'],[<timestamp>,'September, 2004'],...,[<timestamp>,'January, 2005]],
  ...
}
```

You'll have to create the timestamps the same way you've created them for your data, but that's about it.